# Перевод левых определений с английского языка

Tags: лексика, переводы

В английском языке существует понятие левого определения, когда существительное стоит слева от другого определяемого существительного, например, "underground railway". Здесь underground - подземка, railway - железная дорога. На русский язык это переводится как "подземная железная дорога".

Как правильно переводить подобные выражения, когда слева стоит имя собственное, которое не может быть прилагательным, например, "Gudson railway". Варианты, которые приходят на ум:

- железная дорога Гудзона,
- железная Гудзон-дорога (как-то криво получается),

Кроме того, любопытен случай, когда оба существительных являются именами собственными, то есть мы имеем что-то вроде "Gudson Railway".

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос интересный, как говорит коллега, преподаватель английского, потому что ни в одной грамматике нет акцента на имена собственные. Возможен такой перевод: Гудзоновская железная дорога  -   по аналогии с русским  Николаевская железная дорога.

Answer (score 1):

Строго по букварю перевод - Ж/д Гудзона. Но для случая именованных объектов перевод типа "Гудзоновская дорога" столь же возможен. Дело не в железной дороге и не в аналогиях, просто эти две конструкции воспринимаются на русском синононимичными. Сравните: институт Пастера и Пастеровский институт.

Только не пытайтесь переводить "Гудзон-дорога", это русскому языку совершенно чуждо.

Вот насчет двух имён собственных - не понимаю. Пример можно?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы так перевела: железная дорога Гудзон.